# How install PHP extension mongodb on MAMP

Tags: mongodb, composer-php, mamp, php-extension, macos-mojave

I installed yii2, composer and MAMP
but when i do composer update i have error

```
   - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.1.7 requires ext-mongodb >=1.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.1.6 requires ext-mongodb >=1.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.1.5 requires ext-mongodb >=1.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.1.4 requires ext-mongodb >=1.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.1.3 requires ext-mongodb >=1.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.1.2 requires ext-mongodb >=1.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.1.1 requires ext-mongodb >=1.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.1.0 requires ext-mongodb >=1.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-mongodb ^2.1 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-mongodb[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.7].
```

I surfed the entire Internet and did not find a solution

Answer (score -1):

to mongodb extension install do

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```